# Node.js: Stripe post route is not redirecting

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am having a problem with setting up the Stripe API. Everything is working fine, charges are being processed and showing up on my Stripe dashboard.

However, when I try to redirect after the charge has been processed nothing happens. Here is my POST route.

```
router.post('/stripe', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: req.session.cart.totalPrice * 100,
        currency: 'usd',
        description: 'Pay for coffee',
        source: req.body.id
    });

    req.session.cart = new Cart({});
    req.user.paid += charge.amount;        
    await req.user.save();
    res.redirect('/');

} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
});
```

Comment: Try using full path like `http://example.com/`

Comment: @sidgujrathi while paths can be fully qualified, they can also be relative which is often better as you may not know the full path if your application is run across multiple environments, IE: open source software.

Comment: @HPJM is req.user.save() actually returning? It looks like there might be an issue causing some sort of unhandled promise exception in there.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn It's returning, the paid amount is being saved to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of banging my head against the desk I solved the issue after asking for help from a more experienced developer. Basically, the callback sending the Stripe token involved an action generator. That action generator sent an AJAX request to the back-end. AJAX requests won't change content displayed on the screen on a redirect. The answer lay in changing the logic on the front-end.

My solution was to export the `StripeCheckout` component (I'm using `react-stripe-checkout`) with `withRouter`. Then, I passed in the `history` prop into my action generator. In the action generator, I used `history.push()` to redirect after the AJAX request completed.

```
export const handleToken = (token, history) => async dispatch => {
   try {
       const res = await axios.post('/api/stripe', token);
       history.push('/');        
       dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_CART', payload: res.data });
   } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
   }
}
```